# Failure during task do_patch() in BitBake

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using yocto.  It doesn't support ft5x06sbased touchscreens, so I decided to add a patch.  But when I added the patch file, I got the following errors:

```
ERROR: Command Error: exit status: 1  Output:
Applying patch 0026-imx6q-smx6-edt-ft5x06.patch
patching file Documentation/devicetree/bindings/input/touchscreen/edt-ft5x06.txt
patching file drivers/input/touchscreen/edt-ft5x06.c
Hunk #22 FAILED at 751.
Hunk #23 succeeded at 811 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #24 FAILED at 922.
Hunk #25 FAILED at 959.
Hunk #26 FAILED at 995.
Hunk #27 FAILED at 1009.
Hunk #28 succeeded at 1077 (offset 17 lines).
5 out of 28 hunks FAILED -- rejects in file drivers/input/touchscreen/edt-ft5x06.c
Patch 0026-imx6q-smx6-edt-ft5x06.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
ERROR: Function failed: patch_do_patch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/safedrive/test/build/tmp/work/smarc_samx6i-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-smx6/3.10.17-r0/temp/log.do_patch.29885
ERROR: Task 70 (/home/safedrive/test/sources/meta-fsl-arm-extra/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-smx6_3.10.17.bb, do_patch) failed with exit code '1'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is related to task `do_patch()` executed by **BitBake** which in Yocto is a tasks scheduler and executor.
Read more in [BitBake User Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html)

But the error you're facing isn't caused by Yocto components.
The error message says that your patch could not be applied to desired file because it's invalid.

Generally `.patch` is ordered in pieces called `hunks` generated via diff tool.

Example of a single hunk (from [Diff Utility article @ wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility))

```
@@ -5,16 +11,10 @@
be shown if it doesn't
change.  Otherwise, that
would not be helping to
-compress the size of the
-changes.
-This paragraph contains
-text that is outdated.
-It will be deleted in the
-near future.
+compress anything.
```

In the wiki article you can read how to interpret such a hunk, but making it short: line with `-` means that specific patch will remove it, line with `+` is going to be added by patch. Line without any marks are placed for reference (context) and will remain the same.

Now, in your error message it is written:

> 5 out of 28 hunks FAILED -- rejects in file drivers/input/touchscreen/edt-ft5x06.c
>   Patch 0026-imx6q-smx6-edt-ft5x06.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)

It meas that your patch contains 28 hunks as presented above, and 5 of them could not be applied because are invalid - patch tool can't apply those changes because corresponding lines are different than in file you have used as a reference.

It also can be seen that your patch is numbered as 0026, so the probable cause of failure is that other patches applied before your one changed the file structure: ensure that as a reference you are using the source with all existing patches applied.

I assume that you use `*.bbappend` or `*.bb` file to add your patch by appending the `SRC_URI` variable. The order in applying patches is the same as the order of listed files. So if your patch is the newest one it should look like:

```
SRC_URI += "file://0001-<patch_name>.patch \
            file://0002-<patch_name>.patch \
            (...)
            file://0026-imx6q-smx6-edt-ft5x06.patch \
           "
```

And the last remark: if you're using Yocto release >= 1.8 there is a handy thing called `devtool` ([Yocto Mega Manual: devtool](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#using-devtool-in-your-workflow)) and it simplifies working with temporary sources a lot.

**EDIT:**
Question from comment:

> Yes I want to know why bitbake return this error message

Simply because your patch can be applied because it doesn't fit on the target sources.
For a specific recipe a set of task is executed, see: [BitBake manual: Execution chapter](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#bitbake-user-manual-execution). You can list the tasks by passing: `bitbake -c listtasks -f <recipe_name>`. `do_patch()` is one of the common tasks and it fails because of wrong patch.

Try this:

1. Remove your patch from `SRC_URI`.
2. Execute: `bitbake -c cleanall -f <recipe_name>`
3. Execute: `bitbake -c build -f <recipe_name>`
4. Find the directory with sources you need to patch: `bitbake -e <your_recipe_name> | grep ^S=` and go there.
5. Copy the file/files you need to patch. Add to them your changes where you need. Create new patch via `diff` tool. As a reference use original file/files and as a changed the one(s) with your modifications, e.g.: `diff --ruN original_src modified_src > 0026-patch-name.patch`.
6. Move patch to appropriate directory and add it to `SRC_URI`.
7. Rebuild the target recipe: `bitbake -c cleanall -f <recipe_name> && bitbake -c build -f <recipe_name>`

Please notice: `<recipe_name>` should be passed without the `.bb` extension.

Comment: Hi, I thank you for your valuable information regarding my question. I have already added the Patch as per you said above. Could you tell me how can i understand the above error message for rectification of that error.

Comment: Great it works now! What exactly do you want to know? Why BitBake returned error from your question or why patch wasn't applied?

Comment: Yes I want to know why bitbake return this error message !